# Collision Detection with edges Java

Tags: java, processing

I am attempting to add collision detection with the edges using 4 images which represent a walking man. Once the image hits the wall it should reverse and move the other way until it hits the wall and reverses direction once again. How would i go about this? Here is my code so far:

```java
class Walker {
    int x = 0;
    int y;
    int speed;
    PImage img1, img2, img3, img4;
    int count = 0;

    Walker(int y, int speed) {
        this.y = y;
        img1 = loadImage("walk1.gif");
        img2 = loadImage("walk2.gif");
        img3 = loadImage("walk3.gif");
        img4 = loadImage("walk4.gif");
        this.speed = speed;

    }

    void render() {

        if (count < 10)
            image(img1, x, y);
        else if (count < 20)
            image(img2, x, y);
        else if (count < 30)
            image(img3, x, y);
        else if (count < 40)
            image(img4, x, y);
        else {
            count = -1;
        }
        count++;

    }

    void move() {
        x = x + speed;
    }

}


Walker walter;

void setup() {
    size(500, 500);
    walter = new Walker(150, 3);
}

void draw() {
    background(125);
    walter.render();
    walter.move();
}
```

Comment: *How would I go about this?* is a bit vague for this site. What specific problem are you having? What is your observed vs expected output?

Comment: i used
 if (x>=500)
 x = -x;

this results in the image walking through the edges

Comment: You should reverse the speed when you reach the wall to walk in the other direction.

Comment: Assuming that your "allowed walking space" is 0 to 500, you can test for <= 0 and for >=500, but you have to account for your character's width too if you don't want him to go slightly too far, as it's x position is in the "top left" corner of his image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reverse the speed, when ever the walker hits the wall. The width of an [`PImage`](https://processing.org/reference/PImage.html) is given by the property `.width` e.g.:

```java
class Walker {

    // [...]

    void move()
    {
        x = x + speed;

        int man_width = img1.width; 
        if (x <= 0 || x >= width-man_width)
            speed = -speed;
    }
}
```